# Error : Failed to fetch cordova plugin

Tags: cordova, cordova-plugins, onsen-ui

Installing "cordova-plugin-opentokjs" for android
Failed to install 'cordova-plugin-opentokjs':

> CordovaError: Failed to fetch plugin cordova-plugin-crosswalk-webview via registry.
>
> Probably this is either a connection problem, or plugin spec is incorrect.
>
> Check your connection and plugin name/version/URL.
>
> Error: npm: Command failed with exit code 1 Error

Help me to solve this issue?

Comment: did you find any solution ? I also go stuck.

Answer (score 1):

If you use cordova version > 7 install the plugin with the --nofetch flag as mentioned [here](https://cordova.apache.org/news/2017/05/04/cordova-7.html)